# Correct way to start back ground work ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm building a ASP.NET MVC 5 web page currently. It's worth noting I'm fairly new to ASP.NET itself, prior to this I've only dealt with windows desktop applications.

My question is I'm unsure where to start my recurring background work. This work fires checks and updates to the MySql database on the server every few seconds. Currently I'm starting these checks just by adding a start method in the RouteConfig.cs class which I know is the wrong way to do it, just a quick hack while I search for the correct method. Where should I be starting this background work which should be kicked off as soon as the web page is available not when it's first searched for via the browser by a user?

This brings me to another question, a lot more work seemingly but would it be a better/more standard solution to write the background work as a windows service and establish a sort of interface between the web page front end and the windows service?

Comment: I would create a console app and then schedule to run it via windows task scheduler. But if this console app needs to be running round the clock, then I would make it a windows service.

Comment: Thanks CodingYoshi. A windows service in my opinion/knowledge sounds the most logical solution but is it possible/correct to ever do "around the clock" background work from the asp.net web page?

Comment: If the background work doesn't affect the current page it should not be part of the ASP application. You should separate this work in either a Windows Service or Task. If it needs to be kicked off often I would use a Windows Service and Timer.

Comment: If your site is not running, the work will not be done. Also, this will take up resources from the site such as thread(s). Lastly, you are mixing concerns.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, CodingYoshi. The background work relies on the config specified in the asp.net web page, but the web page does not rely on the background work in any form. With both your input I think it's best to do the work in a windows service. As said if the web page is down it can then function manually with its own default configuration.

Comment: You can use Hangfire scheduler that works with net core.  It can be installed from the nuget package manager.  I currently use it for my Azure web app and works great.

Answer (score 0):

Search for Quartzin package manager, its best schedular for .net